# Metatool for automatic xml code generation

Tags: xml, visual-programming

I want to develop a programming tool for developers which can do  automatic xml code generation for specifying a GUI design and its controls. The aim is to allow non-programmers specify GUI controls(which in this case perform  higher level task unlike WinForms ) from a GUI. So the  xml code generated is essentially an internal representation which programmers can understand and further use in any automatic GUI generator.

So the workflow is GUI(computer-novices)->xml(for programmers)->GUI(computer-novices).
Is there a Microsoft project similar to this?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a Microsoft project similar to this?

Expression Blend -> XAML -> Visual Studio

Comment: +1 . I think you are correct. You may want to add some more explanation or a link explaining how to use the workflow.

Comment: @Preet: The workflow is pretty trivial. You can open the same project file in either tool.

Comment: this one seems like GUI(non-programmers)->xml(for programmers)->IDE(programmers)... and then one more step is required to get the final usable app by non-programmers..
Also, expression blend is for designers.I want something that can be used by people having little computer experience....i'll edit that

Comment: you can always go back to the GUI at any time. In fact, the programmer and the designer could both continue making changes.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should create a Domain-Specific Language (DSL) to describe the problem domain of a GUI. Then have your tool consume instances of this DSL to generate the code.

---

In writing this answer, I was thinking of the capabilities of the [Domain-Specific Language Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126235.aspx) from Microsoft, part of the Visual Studio SDK. They allow you to create DSL and a graphical designer that can be used to create instance documents. The instance documents are in XML, with a schema produced by the DSL tools.

The toolkit is precisely targeted to a framework that will consume instance documents and use the to generate code or other text-based artifacts as part of a Visual Studio project.

An example of its use is the [Web Service Software Factory](http://www.codeplex.com/servicefactory), which combines three of these DSLs to generate the service contract, data contract, and hosting configuration for WCF services.

Comment: absolutely..the xml will be a new scema and something like xaml/yaml etc, but how to start developing this? this is more like designing a visual programming language rather than a IDE - what if this VPL is a web-app(even better)?